# Cannot delete Parse object in swift - ACL issue?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, acl

I am having an issue deleting a Parse object in Swift. I keep getting the common error

> [Error]: Object not found. (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0)

I did a lot of research and this typically has to do with ACL issues. However, the ACL looks correct for the authenticated user trying to delete the object.

```
_acl": {
    "*": {
        "r": true
    },
    "H0NwsFHjgL": {
        "r": true,
        "w": true
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that the object is the one I am specifying and that the user is the one I am assuming and is authenticated. I have been banging my head against this for days! Any help would be appreciated!!! Thanks!

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Place")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(thisPlace.placeID!, block: {(object,error) -> Void in
    if(error == nil)
    {
        print(object)
        print(object?.ACL)
        print(object?.objectId)
        print(PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)
        print(PFUser.currentUser()?.authenticated)

        //Error here
        object?.deleteInBackground()

    }
    else
    {
        print("Post delete failed")
        print(error)
    }

})
```

As an FYI I am using `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions` to authenticate. Don't know if that matters...

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... Probably not the best practice but I logged in with the access token after calling PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions and that seemed to work!

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())
```

Comment: And when it was not working for you? when you tried to login with email and password ?